# Finding largest value when rolling two dice among a list of three dice

Tags: python

I have the following function which takes as input two (2) six-sided dice and determines which die among them has the larger number.  **Note that the dice do not necessarily have the numbers 1-6.**

```
def count_number_of_wins(die_1, die_2):

    die_1_larger = 0
    die_2_larger = 0

    for i in range(6):
        for j in range(6):
            if die_1[i] > die_2[j]:
                die_1_larger += 1
            elif die_1[i] < die_2[j]:
                die_2_larger +=1
        

    return (die_1_larger, die_2_larger)
```

Now, I use this function to determine which die is "best" among them an input list of three dice.  I take a list of dice and determine whether one die is better than the others in the list.  A die is "better" if it wins more frequently.  In this case, I return its 0-based index.  If no such die exists, then I return -1.

Here is the function for that:

```
def determine_best_die(dice):
    assert all(len(dice) == 6 for die in dice)

    wins = [0] * len(dice)
    
    for i in range(len(dice)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(dice)):
            a, b = count_number_of_wins(dice[i], dice[j])
            if a > b:
                wins[i] = wins[i] + 1
            else:
                wins[j] = wins[j] + 1
    for i in wins:
        if (i == (len(dice)-1)):
            return wins.index(i)
```

This function is failing for this case:

```
[1, 1, 6, 6, 8, 8], [2, 2, 4, 4, 9, 9], [3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7]
```

I would expect it to return -1, and it's returning 0.

Can anyone see where the issue is in the `determine_best_die()` function?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the expected output -1? It seems like the 2nd dice wins the 1st dice, the 3rd dice wins the 2nd dice, and the 1st dice wins the 3rd dice, so there's no natural ordering of the dice

Comment: Yes, the expected value is -1 for that test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def count_number_of_wins(die_1, die_2):

    die_1_larger = 0
    die_2_larger = 0

    for i in range(6):
        for j in range(6):
            if die_1[i] > die_2[j]:
                die_1_larger += 1
            elif die_1[i] < die_2[j]:
                die_2_larger +=1
        

    return (die_1_larger, die_2_larger)

def determine_best_die(dice):
    assert all(len(die) == 6 for die in dice)

    wins = [0] * len(dice)
    
    for i in range(len(dice)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(dice)):
            a, b = count_number_of_wins(dice[i], dice[j])
            if a > b:
                wins[i] = wins[i] + 1
            else:
                wins[j] = wins[j] + 1
    for i in wins:
        if (i == (len(dice)-1)):
            return wins.index(i)
    return -1
```

I added the case for -1 which happens when there is no dice that wins all the rest. The assertion statement was also checking the len(dice) instead of len(die)

```
print (determine_best_die([[3,3, 6, 6, 8, 8], [2, 2, 4, 4, 9, 9], [3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7]]))
```

returns 0 as the first die wins both the second and third die, while the original failed test case

```
print (determine_best_die([[1, 1, 6, 6, 8, 8], [2, 2, 4, 4, 9, 9], [3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7]]))
```

returns -1